# Automate command lines

Tags: bash, automation

I executing following cmd lines and now I need to put it in a script that I can call and pass file1, file2, file3 as arguments.

```
sort file1.csv > file1.csv.sorted
sort file2.csv > file2.csv.sorted 
diff --speed-large-files \
  file1.csv.sorted \
  file2.csv.sorted \
  > file3.difftmp
rm file1.csv.sorted
rm file2.csv.sorted
```

I have tried to create bash script, but following eval was not working:

```
s="diff --speed-large-files $file1.csv.sorted $file2.csv.sorted > $file3"
eval s
```

I do not necessarily need to create a bash script, but I need to automate this process so that other processes could call it and pass arguments.

Comment: [Do not use strings for commands. Use arrays.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) And "so that other processes could call it and pass arguments" is **exactly** what a script is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `eval` here; a simple function will suffice:

```
filediff() {
   sort "$1".csv > "$1".csv.sorted
   sort "$2".csv > "$2".csv.sorted 
   diff --speed-large-files "$1".csv.sorted "$2".csv.sorted > "$3".difftmp
   rm "$1".csv.sorted
   rm "$2".csv.sorted
}
```

As Tom Fenech suggested, you can also use process substitution and avoid creating temporary files.

Answer (score 3):

As you're using bash, you can take advantage of process substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash
diff --speed-large-files <(sort "$1") <(sort "$2")
```

You can pass the two file names to the script as arguments. This avoids the creation of temporary files and the need for manual cleanup.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. However when I was running diff on two large fiies 16GB and 17GB I run out of memory when using process substitution.

Comment: @Edijs with files of that size, I'm not surprised that you ran out of memory!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you could just do

```
k=$(s)
```

So `k` is a variable where the result returned from command `s` is stored. If you want to use a string as s command, do `$("cmd")`